# PDO exec doesn't work, database remains empty

Tags: php, database, sqlite, pdo

I have written this code:

```
$database = new PDO('sqlite:./shoxxdb.sqlite3');
if (!$database) {
  include './shoxx/error.php';
  exit;
}
$database->exec('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Feeds (ID UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY, Name, URL)');
$database->exec('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Articles (ID UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY, FeedID, Title, Body, URL, Date)');
```

But when ran, `shoxxdb.sqlite3` remains empty, even though the permissions are set to `0666`. Surprisingly I don't get any error message.

I have PHP version 5.3.4 on Mac OS X.

Can anyone help me please? This is driving me crazy.

Comment: Mmm, very strange. I tried to put it in a try block but it doesn't seem to throw an exception either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlite.php
"The folder that houses the database file must be writeable." Is it?

And about errors, pls check, that you have enable them in php.ini -- may be you have errors, but they didn't displayed.

Comment: Thankx! I put the database in a new directory with permissions `0777` and now it works perfectly.